# How to use data collected from any form in Controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner and I am not getting any tutorial or something which can help me understand how to process data collected from forms in Laravel.

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with? `Input::get()` & `Input::all()` are about all I need, the rest is just non-laravel specific php code..

Answer (score 1):

Use [Laravel's `Input` class](http://laravel.com/docs/input#input):

```
$name = Input::get('name');
```

This return data from both `$_GET` & `&_POST` (and some more).

Comment: Can you tell me where should I write(conventional location) the logic of processing data?In route.php file or controller file or some where else.

Comment: Controllers are optional. If you are using a controller then this is where it should go. Otherwise it should go in the route. Depending on the type of logic, some things may be better suited for the model. I usually put things like date formatting or wysiwyg sanitation in the save method on the model.